# Database selection for payroll management

Tags: android

I am developing my first android app which is payroll management, but I have no idea about which database should be used for this application. Sqlite or mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the database to be stored in the app (on the device) you must use SQLite. But if you have the database on an external server to which you are connecting, you can use MySql and you can perform queries using JSon.

If you give us more information we can help you better

Comment: this application contains attendance upload by employees to leader and each employee has his own id password

Answer (score 0):

This depends where you are storing the data. If you store the data on a server you can use SQLite (if it's not much data) or MySQL or another larger database (if you store data for hundreds or more users).

If you store it directly on the device you can only use SQLite (or similar alternatives).